# OpenCV and numpy version mismatch

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, opencv

How to check what version of openCV is compatible with a particular version of numpy?

I am using python 2.7.5 and installed numpy 1.7.1 on windows 7.
As i am working under firewall and I don't have any access to any proxy, hence I cant use pip or any windows provided packages like anaconda or cobra etc.

How can i create the environment with python2, openCV and numpy manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the other users, I have found a solution to do the installation the hard way...

1. Install Python 2.7.0
2. download the numpy package from github. Unzip the package.
3. Locate this numpy package in command prompt.
4. type the command: python setup.py bdist_wininst

This command will convert into a binary distribution which cna be easily installed.

This link will further explain the manual process to install the python module:
https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html[1]

Answer (score 0):

**Try with below steps:**

```
pip install pipenv
```

then install your package with pipenv

```
pipenv install opencv
```

This will install all dependency related to package.No need to do any extra efforts.

Comment: pip does not work because of the firewalls setup in the office.
I can install these packages from github or the other external sources but cant do it from the pip install link

Comment: I have not used pipenv, but if your only problem is with the `pip` part, note that it can install from a [local tarball](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#id25) or indeed from a [local repository](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-a-local-src-tree).  So perhaps you could look on pypi to find the exact link, download manually, and then use pip to manage installation?